# Clarifications regarding LSTM

Tags: neural-networks, python, lstm, keras

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

net = Sequential()
net.add(LSTM(units = 3, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
net.add(LSTM(units = 3))
net.add(Dense(units = 1))
```

Below image is an attempt to visually represent the above code snippet.

[image]

From the above figure, I understand that there are two layers of LSTM units. Each of those layers has three LSTM units/neurons. There is a single output neuron/unit. The same input is fed to all three LSTM units in the first layer.

---

**My Questions:**

a) Does the figure interpret the code sample correctly?

b) Have I described/understood the figure correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your figure is rather accurate, yet missed one important step.
In the first LSTM layer you pass a parameter `return_sequences = True` which passed the whole sequence of first layer to the second layer. In contrast, Dense layer receives only the last output of second LSTM layer.
I've sketched a picture of your code given a sequence on 4 input elements ($x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$).[image]
Each row represents a single LSTM layer. Each LSTM block contains 3 units/neurons. Within the block neurons are connected and can exchange information between sequence steps.

I would recommend this [blog post](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) to understand LSTM more.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, from your figure I understand that the LSTM unit has been unrolled to accommodate the input sequences(x1 x2 x3 x4).

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I have read Colah's blog post on LSTM. I kind of have a fair understanding of how LSTM works. But, I'm struggling to understand how it looks and functions as a whole neural network.  [Q] What do you mean by "Each LSTM block contains 3 units/neurons" ?? Doesn't the LSTM block represent a neuron?

Comment: LSTM block would be a a cube on the graph. Typically LSTM block has more than one neuron inside. Say in your example on 3 neurons, when you are computing, say, forget gate $f_t$ then all hidden state variables $h_(t-1)$ are considered for each neuron. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can I say that each neuron will have all the gates of the LSTM?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. All gates will be applied to each neuron.

Comment: I happen to find [this][1] post which contradicts with your representation of code or am I missing something? Could you please help me with a clarification.


  [1]: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24909/the-model-of-lstm-with-more-than-one-unit?rq=1&newreg=a156c5e8979240b3981ccf2c4a53ef19

Comment: That post missed cell connections. You can take a look at Tensorflow implementation or this blog (http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-network-tutorial-part-4-implementing-a-grulstm-rnn-with-python-and-theano/) and try to implement your own LSTM cell. You will notice that hidden state vector (cells) are multiplied by a weight matrix which introduces intracell connections.